# Event on BrowserWindow when page is not found in Electron?

Tags: electron

Is there an event I can listen for when the page is not found in a browser window?

Example:

```
  win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true
    }
  })

  // url has typo 
  var url = __dirname + "indez.html";
  console.log("Loading app: " + url);

  win.loadFile(url);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can listen to ["did-fail-load" event](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/web-contents#event-did-fail-load).

```
  win.webContents.on("did-fail-load", (event, errorCode) => {
    console.log("did-fail-load - errorCode:", errorCode);
  });
```